# Browser hangs when clicked on a button in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click an image button on the below link which is "Get Data"
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

I am filling details using these lines into the fields

```
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @id='rdDateToDate']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='symbol' and @type='text']").send_keys("TCS")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='textboxdata hasDatepicker' and @id='fromDate']").send_keys("11-04-2017")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='textboxdata hasDatepicker' and @id='toDate']").send_keys("10-04-2018")
```

But when I click on the Get Data button using these lines, the browser hangs
I have tried these three things,

1] `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and @value='Get Results']").click()`

which says 'Message: element not interactable'

2] `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='getdata-button' and @id='get']").click()`

which hangs the browser

3]

```
buttonClick = driver.find_element_by_class_name("getdata-button");
buttonClick.click();
```

which also hangs the browser

Please help me out

Comment: hmm.. I have seen this behavior earlier for the mentioned website , seems like they detect Selenium as a bot and do not let us scrape using Selenium.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='getdata-button']").click()` works on https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm. If yours was the case then wouldn't it be across all the sites? @cruisepandey

Comment: But I have noticed one thing, if I fill in the details and then click the button it doesn't work. It works only when nothing is filled @cruisepandey

Comment: There's some sort of issue while scrapping through Selenium, manually it works well